# Is it possible to resize all images on a page to a specific size?

Tags: css, image, resize

I am creating an email flyer and I have multiple images that I want at 140px by 140px but some are originally 300x300 or 400x400. I don't want to go resize each image as there can be quite a few and the flyer will be a weekly update so is it possible to use CSS to tell all images (or images that have classes) to resize to 140px?

I was going to post some code but it's quite a vague request so there no relevant code I can show to help my question.

maybe if I `<span>...</span>` and then give the span a class, would it be possible this way?

Comment: Try with javascript. The easiest way that I can think of quickly now is to fetch all images on page load and set their size to the size you want.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using JS for email flyers, most email providers will detect JS as possible spam.

Comment: Nah, no need to use javascript for simple needs like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your markup is for a newsletter you may force dimensions both with `style` attribute and with inline `width` and `height` attribute, e.g.

```
<img src="..." style="width:140px; height:140px" width="140" height="140" />
```

but, anyway, I strongly suggest to perform some kind of batch task for automatic resize of the images (e.g. using [GruntJS](https://github.com/excellenteasy/grunt-image-resize)), so you could save some precious bandwidth on the server in which you store your static assets. (conversely, if you embed images into the email, users will appreciate a lighter size)

Comment: perfect, thanks. This will work best as it's inline CSS, more email friendly :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah add class to span and then:

```
span.yourclass img {
width: 140px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your images with `div.class` then write a single css to resize all the images which are wrapped by that div

**MARK-UP::**

```
 <div class="imageWrapper">
     <img src="/path/to" />
     <img src="/path/to" />
     <img src="/path/to" />
 </div>
```

**CSS::**

```
.imageWrapper{
     overflow:hidden;
 }

.imageWrapper img{
   width:400px;
   height:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I might be understanding this, but some simple css should work :

css :

```
img.small {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
}
```

OR if you want to do all img's under a specific element :

```
.thumbs img {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
}
```

html :

```
<img src="pic.jpg" class="small">

<div class="thumbs">
    <img src="pic.jpg">
    <img src="pic.jpg">
    <img src="pic.jpg">
</div>
```

Or if they are dynamically generated, you can eliminate the css and just go :

```
<img src="pic.jpg" width="140" height="140">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set width and height for all images. Add "max" keyword to be sure.

```
img{
   max-width:140px !important;
   max-height:140px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want ALL images on the page to resize, add the following into your CSS:

```
img{ width: 140px; }
```

This will proportionally set the height/width and I'm assuming all you images are square ?
If not, add 'height: 140px' but this will distort an image that isn't square.